# Replace/Update Value in Column Using If statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Consider this example. There are two columns one called grade with a number 1-10 and another called status that says pass or fail. Originally, any number 1-6 resulted in fail and everything from 7-10 said pass.

```
Grade | Status
  1   |  Fail
  2   |  Fail
  3   |  Fail
  4   |  Fail
  5   |  Fail
  6   |  Fail
  7   |  Pass
  8   |  Pass
  9   |  Pass
 10   |  Pass
```

Now I lowered the passing grade to a 6. I want to replace every fail in the status column with pass if it has a grade of 6. How would I do this using an if statement in Excel?

Comment: Just replace the first cell with the new formula, and then drag to rest of cells. Other option would be having both columns in a Table, so when you update the formula in the first cell, it will update rest of rows inside table

Comment: Did you ***really*** want to do this with VBA? If not, it's a simple in sheet formula.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you're looking for a simple `IF` statement for your worksheet. If so, try this:

`=IF(A2<6,"Fail","Pass")`

Take this formula and drag it down your range, adjusting where necessary.

#### Below are some screens I threw together to show the formula a bit better.

---

This is how I assumed you had your original worksheet set up:

[image: Original assumed setup]

And this is how I set it up based on your request:

[image: Requested setup]